# options_from_collection_for_select's text_method date conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date-conversion

I intend to create a dropdown for selection.

Expected Outcome:

```
March 2016
August 2016
```

With these code, as my dropdown is showing as below as database is storing the YY-MM-DD

```
2016-03-01
2016-08-01
```

Here's my code:

```
<%= form_tag('/admin/users', method: :get) do %>
<%= select_tag "intake_date", options_from_collection_for_select(Membership.select(:intake_date).distinct, 'intake_date', 'intake_date')%>
<%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

I've tried changing the `text_method` in `options_from_collection_for_select` to

`Membership.all.pluck(:intake_date).uniq.inject{ |date| date.strftime(%B %Y) }`

but the outcome is still not as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both the `value` and `text` methods for collection select can respond to a method call, which yields the instance of the object, the result would be used for select options.

In your case, you should be able to solve with:

```
select_tag 'intake_date', options_from_collection_for_select(Membership.pluck(:intake_date), :to_s, proc{|date| date.strftime("%B %Y")})
```

This is assuming you will parse the date before saving the record in your db, as the value method is a date string

Comment: Great answer. Thank you!